# Input field is filled, but content is not saved using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE, I'm able to fill an input field (using "type" command), but when I "save" the value, this value is lost. Doing the same by hand, everything works fine.
Any hint to solve this issue? I've already tried using typeKeys command.

The code inside the target page is:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<div id="editDiv" class="editDialog">
 <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td width="25%" style="">period</td>
    <td align="right" width="25%" style="padding: 6px;">
     <input id="period" type="text" onblur="changeValue(this.id, this.value, undefined)">
     <br>
     <label>da 0 a 9</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="applyChanges()">
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="removeEditDialog(false)">
</div>
```

To help more on this issue:

```
function changeValue(id, value, paramPos) {
 var par = tempGlobalParams[id] ? tempGlobalParams[id] : tempGlobalPaintingsParams[paramPos][id];
 if(checkRules(id, value, paramPos)){
  par.custom = value;
 }
```

Comment: It could be something to do with the changeValue function which is being called by onblur (i.e. when the field loses focus). Can you show the source code for that changeValue function?

Comment: Thank you vincebowdren, I've updated the description with the function as you required.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like the `changeValue` function itself does anything to alter the input field, but it calls another function `checkRules` which might do. Do you have the source code for that one?